# Why are CONKY memory RAM use stats higher than HTOP?

Tags: ram, htop, conky

I have two different setups, one on virtual machine, and one standard, both on Linux, one on MINT and the other on MX. But on both, the CONKY stats for idle system RAM usage are around 200MB higher than HTOP stats for the same idle state. Why is this? What is not listed in HTOP or counted in HTOP that is counted in CONKY?

Comment: Is it that difficult a question?